# Unwrap uint8 frame counter

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a uint8 frame counter that repeats from 0 to 255 but can potentially drop frames, what's the best way to convert this to a 1 based total frame counter? For example, if the data repeats 0 to 255 3 times but the final 254 is missing, I want the frame counter to be 1 to 768 but with 767 missing.

Comment: Just use bigger int type?

Comment: It's a throughput limitation.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that a bigger int will be too slow?